# What makes the melody so counterintuitive in the chorus/refrain of Light my Fire?

Tags: theory, voice, melody

In the song light my fire by the doors, the refrain of the chorus repeats: “c’mon baby, light my fire”

The last 3-4 syllables have something interesting going on in the variations that come with each repetition of the melody/theme.

For some reason it is much more difficult to familiarise one’s vocal memory with so that it becomes fresh and easily recallable by the brain and vocal cords.

What gives these melodies these properties of being quirky, yet musically satisfying, and counter intuitive?

Comment: I don't hear the same effect you're hearing, but I bet the answer is probably that the melody is not similar to the melodies you normally listen to.  This melody is different than what your intuition was trained on, thus "counterintuitive."

Comment: Thanks for the perspective.